# Accessing Google Chrome network tag using python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to access the networks tab you get in Google Chrome dev tools on this link: https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login

So I need a list of the links of the files you see in the networks tab and please note that I'm not going to be using Selenium or the Chrome webdriver since they can be pretty slow.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login"

with requests.session() as s:

    r = s.get(login_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup.prettify())

    network = None
```

Comment: Try `t = [s.attrs['src'] for s in soup.select('script[src],img[src]')]  + [s.attrs['href'] for s in soup.select('link[href]')]`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule That pretty much worked! Thank you!

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Doesn't exactly get all the network files though.